# Запятая ставится?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, перечисление

**Он проработал в школе 20 лет(,) 5 месяцев и 1 день.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае правильное написание предложения будет таково: "Он проработал в школе 20 лет 5 месяцев и 1 день". Запятая не требуется, так как предложение не осложнено.

Comment: да, спасибо, с телефона пишу — могу промахнуться.